# Precautions on continuous write()ing into a TCP socket in C++?

Tags: c++, sockets, loops, tcp

Please consider the following code:

```
while (1) { 
    write(send_socket,sending_buffer,bytes_in_buffer);
}
```

Are there any precautions on continuous write()ing (*especially from size point of view*), or the operating system and TCP/IP will tidy up and manage everything?

By the way, is this considered as network throttling?

Comment: This looks more like the opposite of network throttling. However, you will fill the kernel buffers, then `write()` will block until the other side has consumed enough data (or an error occurs).

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, will continuous write()ing fill up my kernel buffers? I.e. does it lead to a system hang?

Comment: Nope, it will only fill the buffers associated with I/O from your process. The program will then go to sleep, but the system will continue humming along the whole time.

Comment: What about my question?

Comment: Leave it here. Someone may come up later and post an extensive answer complete with usual buffer sizes, a section about what would happen if `write()` operates in non-blocking mode, etc.